# Como puedo exportar una funcion de un componente a otro? ANGULAR 2/4

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Buenas stackeros!,

He aprendido ha usar el **Output()/Input()** en Angular 2/4, y mientras practicaba, me ha dado la casualistica de que necesitaba exportar (Output) una funcion que ya tenia creada en un componente, y importarla (Input) a otra.
Sabeis alguna forma de hacerlo?, lo he estado buscando pero no encuentro nada, o no me entero muy bien.

Gracias por la ayuda gente!

Comment: Tienes componente A y B, en A tienes un emisor Output, y quieres pasar el emisor al input de B como función, entonces pásala tal cual y en B la recoges en una variable o como parámetro en otra función y luego ya la utilizas. ¿Esa es tu pregunta?

Comment: Tengo una funcion en A y quiero usarla en B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Desde el componente A, teniendo a componente B como hijo le envías tu variable `Output() myOutput` a su variable `Input() myInput`.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-a-component',
  template: `
    Hello from AComponent
    <app-component-b></app-component-b>
  `
})
export class AComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() myOutput = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @ViewChild(BComponent) bComponent: BComponent;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.bComponent.myInput = this.myOutput;
  }

}
```

> Desde el componente B, estás a la escucha de cambios en los `Input()` hasta que recibes un nuevo cambio en tu `Input() myInput` y ahí puedes estar seguro de que te han enviado 'algo' a esa variable, en tu caso la otra variable del componente A.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-b-component',
  template: `Hello from BComponent`
})
export class BComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() myInput: EventEmitter<any> | null = null;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['myInput']) {
      const myOutputReceived = changes.myInput.currentValue;
      // Aquí estás seguro que has recibido cambios en myInput.
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Gracias Stackero! me has ayudado. Saludos